# I want to truncate my table once a month, otherwise it only deletes data from the past 3 months, how can I conditionally truncate or delete?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, where-clause, case, sql-delete, truncate

I have this variable

```
set is_full_refresh = (
CASE
WHEN DAY(LAST_DAY(current_date)) - DAY(current_date) < 7 AND DAYOFWEEK(current_date) = 5 THEN TRUE
ELSE FALSE END
);
```

And it's only true when it is the last friday of every month. I have a script that deletes part of  a table depending on the date.

```
SET sales_date = (
SELECT MIN(max_date) AS date
FROM (
    SELECT date_type, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM sales_table
    GROUP BY date_type
)a);

SET process_from_date = (SELECT COALESCE(DATEADD('MONTH', -3, DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', $sales_date))::DATE, '2019-01-01'::DATE))

DELETE FROM table
WHERE date >= $process_from_date;
```

How can I use the is_full_refresh variable as a case statement to be like this or is this already possible and I am just missing a select statement?

```
Case when is_full_refresh = true then truncate sales_Table else DELETE FROM sales_table
    WHERE date >= $process_from_date;
```

Comment: Have you considered just scheduling 2 different tasks that run on different schedules?

Comment: I have but there are moments when we just want to delete parts of the table and time when we want to truncate. This helps keep the data fresh and up to date.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Snowflake Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index) logic for this:

```
BEGIN
    let is_full_refresh boolean := CASE
        WHEN DAY(LAST_DAY(current_date())) - DAY(current_date()) < 7 AND DAYOFWEEK(current_date()) = 5 THEN TRUE
        ELSE FALSE END;
    
    IF (is_full_refresh) THEN
        truncate sales_table;
        return 'truncated table';
    ELSE
         let sales_date TIMESTAMP_NTZ := (
            SELECT MIN(max_date) AS date
            FROM (
                SELECT date_type, MAX(date) AS max_date
                FROM sales_table
                GROUP BY date_type
            )a);
        let process_from_date timestamp_ntz := (SELECT COALESCE(DATEADD('MONTH', -3, DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', :sales_date))::DATE, '2019-01-01'::DATE));
        
        DELETE FROM sales_table WHERE date >= :process_from_date;
        
        return 'deleted records older than ' || :process_from_date::string;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Is this script usable in snowflake DB?

Comment: Yes, it's Snowflake Scripting.

Comment: Yes, it should work in snowsight, but If you are using the old console, you'll need to put an "execute immediate" block around it: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples#passing-a-block-as-a-string-literal-to-execute-immediate